# Does the safe pressure of tubeless tire change with a tube?

Tags: tire, innertube, tubeless, tire-pressure

I have a brand new Goodyear Vector 700x28c Tubeless Complete tire and the max PSI written on the sidewall is 85 but the non-tubeless 28c version is 110 PSI. My question is can I pump my tubeless tire with a tube higher than 85 PSI and not get a blowout during a ride? I use clincher or hooked rims.

Answer (score 3):

You should never exceed the range printed on the tyre. Period. You can experiment with going lower, especially when using tubeless, but you should never exceed the maximum pressure.

Be aware that the ranges printed on the tyres, even tubeless-ready ones, often assume an inner tube anyway (and therefore you can go lower - at your own risk - without one).

If you do exceed the pressure, you may find out that nothing bad happened, they are usually tested to ~1.5x the max pressure, but it should not be done. It is a safety margin that should be kept.